# Using JMeter WebDriver sampler can we capture the network request breakdown?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, jmeter-plugins

For example: My login page is taking time to load so, I want request breakdown for this page to know which request is more take time.

Not getting any solution for it.

Comment: didnt get any solution  ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36503092/capture-webdriver-requests-in-jmeter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capture WebDriver requests in Jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36503092/capture-webdriver-requests-in-jmeter)

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to "get any solution" for it for the WebDriver Sampler

It's possible on Selenium level but you will need to set a special capability prior to starting the WebDriver instance: [LoggingPreferences](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/logging/LoggingPreferences.html)

Then you will be able to access the outgoing and incoming requests list using [Logs](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/logging/Logs.html) class instance

Example [Groovy code](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) you could use in the [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler):

```
def options = new org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions()
def logPrefs = new org.openqa.selenium.logging.LoggingPreferences()
logPrefs.enable(org.openqa.selenium.logging.LogType.PERFORMANCE, java.util.logging.Level.ALL);
options.setCapability('goog:loggingPrefs', logPrefs)

def driver = new org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver(options)

driver.get('https://jmeter.apache.org')

List<org.openqa.selenium.logging.LogEntry> entries = driver.manage().logs().get('performance').getAll()

//do what you need here

driver.quit()
```